# can I print the index of an element in an object vector?

Tags: c++, loops, vector

So I know to print something in a loop, the code looks like this:

```
for(int I = 0; I < num; ++I)...
```

And to print an object vector:

```
for(Square sq : squares)...
```

(if I have a class Square and I create the object sq and squares is the name of the vector)

But how would I go about code if I want my output to look like:

square 1 area: 3
square 2 area: 6
square 3 area: 9

To be more clear: my question is, how do I incorporate "I" like in the first example in a loop where I'm printing objects?

Comment: Not sure it answers your question but vectors have `operator[]` so you can access the Nth element with `vec[N]`. For your example, that would mean `squares[i]`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
for (size_t idx=0; idx<squares.size(); ++idx)
{
    Square const & sq = squares[idx];

    // Here you can use both:
    //      idx (which is the index in the vector), 
    //      and sq (reference to the element).
}
```

The fact that `sq` is a `std::vector` does not mean you must traverse it using the range-based loop ([Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)).

A `std::vector` has a method for getting its size ([std::vector::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size)), and operator[] to access an element ([std::vector::operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)).

**Note** - even if you do use the range-based loop, it is better to use a refernce (or const reference) to avoid unnecessary copies:

```
for(Square const & sq : squares)   // without `const` if you need to modify the element
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine range based for and another index variable

```
// with c++20 range-based for can have initializer in it
for(auto i=1; auto& s:squares){ 
   std::cout << "square " << i << " area: " << s << '\n' ;
   ++i;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EfhefdoGP

---

pre-c++20

```cpp
{
   auto i=1;
   for(auto& s:squares){ 
      std::cout << "square " << i << " area: " << s << '\n' ;
      ++i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the elements of the vector are lined up continuously... It may be possible to do something like this.

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object( int a, int b ) : a(a),b(b) {}
    int a,b;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Object> Vec{ {1,2}, {10,20}, {100,200} };
    for( const auto &obj : Vec )
    {
        auto index = &obj - &Vec[0];  //calculate index of element
        std::cout << index << "  : " << obj.a << "," << obj.b << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```